# How to export chart table data to PDF in extjs?

Tags: java, extjs

I try to export my chart table data from DB but have no idea how to export PDF.
Have any suggestion use to export chart table data by using existing extjs information to PDF file? Urgent..!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think extjs has anything built-in to create pdfs. So you will either need to create it on the server or maybe you can use a client side js libary for pdf generation (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/)

Comment: oh... thanks first, but since that time i not able to do it, so i always download .xls first then save as .pdf without auto-generate as PDF format. Anyway, thanks dude... i will try this solution given by you.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would need your server to assist with this. What kind of server do you use?

Otherwise, you could try https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 0):

I am researching about this, I think you first have to convert your chart into a picture and then use a PDF generator library and include this picture on it.
To convert chart to picture:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/charts/Area.js

To generate PDF on c# if you are using it on server side it could be pdfsharp or itext